# Server is not updating

Tags: git, cakephp, webserver, sftp, fortrabbit

I am using fortrabbit as a development server and cakephp as a framework. however I recently experienced an error I could not solve so far:

Commiting and pushing my files from localhost (xampp on windows 7) to the development server works fine except for the whole webroot directory including my CSS and JS files. Sourcetree commits and pushes them as usual, but when I check the directory via Filezilla those files in webroot haven't been updated. If I try to upload files with Filezilla I get (open for write: failure)

Two things that you should know:
Cakephp started to show some "warning 512: disk quota exceeded" about the time webroot was updated for the last time.
Furthermore I added a password prompt to my htaccess via htpasswd protecting the server from unauthorized visitors. 
Maybe this has something to do with it.

Thanks heaps in advance! I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You write english, so I assume you could simply read and understand the error message?

> warning 512: disk quota exceeded

That means the hard drive of the server or the amount of space you're allowed to use is full. Delete some stuff or get more space.

Comment: Thank you - I deleted some files but it was still not possible to upload new files. Not even 1kb files